Realize Instances node does not work on Light objects
I want to bring Blender lights into After Effects, which are instanced with Geometry Nodes. However, the Realize Instances node does not work on Light objects. Am I doing something wrong?

To my understanding, there's nothing to realize: no mesh, no curve, no point cloud etc. Geometry Nodes don't output objects as it's a data modifier that is supposed to only modify data of the object. I think there is some design inconsistency here, but to my understanding it's an intended design. It is possible to write a Python script to convert instances to objects...

@MarkusvonBroady I was surprised to know, that Make Instances Real has been updated and may get instances from GN

@CRANTISZ WOW THAT'S GREAT NEWS!!!

Sure. Realize instances converts geometry to mesh. But you can't convert lights into mesh.
Use Ctrl+A ⇾ Make Instances Real, It will convert lights to real objects, that's can be exported
